# How to inflate layout not from R.layout?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout

Can I send layout to the app or open layout file in android application and inflate it, like it was builded with the application?

Comment: No, you can't. You need to create the layout programmatically instead.

Answer (score 0):

thats not possible according to [DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

> For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime; it only works with an XmlPullParser returned from a compiled resource (R.something file.)